# How to resize a image that is displaying as stretched only on mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, css, image, media-queries

I'm building a site for a friend and I'm having trouble understanding why the client image is stretched the entire vh if I select a client image on a mobile device. When I test the site on a desktop it shows as I would like, however, I'm not sure where the issue is stemming from. Instead of posting my entire code, I have provided the link to my repository and website. The live site can be found https://savetheyardllc.netlify.app/, and my repo for the code is here https://github.com/ddelimond/Johnson-Landscaping, I would really appreciate the help. Sorry for any mistakes in formatting my question or any lack of information, Im new to stack.

[image: mobile Image of the issue][image: Desktop view]

Comment: just set `img { max-width: 100%; object-fit: contain; }`

Comment: @KunalTanwar Thank you that did it, I've been searching for hours to no avail for this, any tips on how to ask better questions or get better at googling?

Answer (score 0):

use object-fit: cover or object-fit: contain

read the guide here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp